# PHP Prepared Statement Non-Object Error

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to convert my php script to use prepared statements and it's giving me an error....anyone know what's wrong?

```
<?php
define("DB_DSN","xxx");
define("DB_HOST","xxx");
define("DB_USER","xxx");
define("DB_PASS","xxx");

$con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db(DB_DSN) or die('Could not select database');
$stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE Level01 SET Deaths=:Deaths WHERE DeathID= :DeathID");
$stmt->bindParam(':Deaths', $deaths);
$stmt->bindParam(':DeathID', $id);

$id = base64_decode($_GET["id"]);
$deaths = base64_decode($_GET["deaths"]);       
$uresult = $stmt->execute();
if(! $uresult )
{
  die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Updated data successfully\n";
mysql_close($con);
exit;
```

This is my error: Fatal Error: Call to member function prepare() on a non-object

Comment: What error do you get? Please be as precise as possible.

Comment: The MySQL extension doesn't support prepared statements: use MySQLi or PDO

Comment: Fatal Error: Call to member function prepare() on a non-object

Comment: @MarkBaker
Thanks for the reply!
I tried both the PDO and the MYSQLI methods, but neither worked....I got an error saying that access is denied to the server. I'm using a free hosting site, so is there any way PDO or MYSQLI would be be banned from use?

Answer (score 4):

`mysql_connect` does not return an MySQLi object but a MySQL resource.

You seem to be mixing MySQL and MySQLi. They are **not** a drop-in replacement for eachother, as MySQL does not support prepared statements. Read the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) again, it is all quite clearly explained there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
I tried both the PDO and the MYSQLI methods, but neither worked....I got an error saying that access is denied to the server. I'm using a free hosting site, so is there any way PDO or MYSQLI would be be banned from use?

Comment: @Alan, probably (possibly?) the extensions are not available. Try to use `php_info()` to find out. If they are not available, run away from that hoster very far, very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You first bind your variables and then assign them. Try the other way round:

```
$id = base64_decode($_GET["id"]);
$deaths = base64_decode($_GET["deaths"]); 

$stmt->bindParam(':Deaths', $deaths);
$stmt->bindParam(':DeathID', $id);
```

If it's not that, then please add the error message you receive

Answer (score 0):

You cant use prepared statements with mysql,use mysqli or PDO.